# Should I call strict mode as 'use strict' or "use strict"?

Tags: javascript

In some documentation for Javascript I have seen strict mode enabled with single quotes as:

`'use strict';`

Yet in other documentation I have seen strict mode enabled with double quotes as:

`"use strict";`

What is the correct way to enable strict mode and why?

EDIT: This question is not asking can I use single quotes, but rather what the generally accepted style is (single quotes or double quotes) and why that style is preferred.

Comment: `use strict` needs to be a string ... if you know javascript, you know the difference between `"` and `'` (hint: there's no difference)

Comment: Use both... just in case. Maybe twice even.

Comment: @Skinny That would be *paranoid mode*…?

Comment: @Nathaniel The *correct* way is the one that works, which is both.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing.Here you can find some more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement "use strict"; (or 'use strict';) before any other statements.